# Codelab(bitbucket.org) example step 6, not working across network

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, xirsys

I am reposting this question as I didn't get working solution previously. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.
I have hosted the example (basic video chat application which use node.js for signalling) shown in step 6 of codelab webrtc demo tutorials on heroku to try using it across different networks. I am using Xirsys STUN/TURN servers for it. It works fine when 2 systems are on same network. But when I try connecting systems across different network, it shows black screen on remote video. I am unable to figure out the problem here. I am attaching the code for main.js .Any help is appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var isChannelReady;
var isInitiator = false;
var isStarted = false;
var localStream;
var pc;
var remoteStream;
var turnReady;

var pc_config = {'iceServers': [
{url:'stun:turn02.uswest.xirsys.com'},
{
    url: 'turn:turn02.uswest.xirsys.com:443?transport=udp',
    credential: 'my_credentials',
    username: 'my_username'
},
{
    url: 'turn:turn02.uswest.xirsys.com:443?transport=tcp',
    credential: 'my_credentials',
    username: 'my_username'
},
{
    url: 'turn:turn02.uswest.xirsys.com:5349?transport=udp',
    credential: 'my_credentials',
    username: 'my_username'
},
{
    url: 'turn:turn02.uswest.xirsys.com:5349?transport=tcp',
    credential: 'my_credentials',
    username: 'my_username'
}

]};

var pc_constraints = {'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}]};

// Set up audio and video regardless of what devices are present.
var sdpConstraints = {'mandatory': {
  'OfferToReceiveAudio':true,
  'OfferToReceiveVideo':true }};

/////////////////////////////////////////////

var room = location.pathname.substring(1);
if (room === '') {
 room = prompt('Enter room name:');
  // room = 'fool';
} else {
  //
}

var socket = io.connect();

if (room !== '') {
  console.log('Create or join room', room);
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
}

socket.on('created', function (room){
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  isInitiator = true;
});

socket.on('full', function (room){
  console.log('Room ' + room + ' is full');
});

socket.on('join', function (room){
  console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' + room);
  console.log('This peer is the initiator of room ' + room + '!');
  isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('joined', function (room){
  console.log('This peer has joined room ' + room);
  isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('log', function (array){
  console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendMessage(message){
  console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
  // if (typeof message === 'object') {
  //   message = JSON.stringify(message);
  // }
  socket.emit('message', message);
}

socket.on('message', function (message){
  console.log('Client received message:', message);
  if (message === 'got user media') {
    maybeStart();
  } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
      maybeStart();
    }
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    doAnswer();
  } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
      sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
      candidate: message.candidate
    });
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  } else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
    handleRemoteHangup();
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

function handleUserMedia(stream) {
  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localStream = stream;
  sendMessage('got user media');
  if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
}

function handleUserMediaError(error){
  console.log('getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

var constraints = {video: true};
getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);

console.log('Getting user media with constraints', constraints);

// if (location.hostname != "localhost") {
//   requestTurn('https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com/turn?username=41784574&key=4080218913');
// }

function maybeStart() {
  if (!isStarted && typeof localStream != 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
    createPeerConnection();
    pc.addStream(localStream);
    isStarted = true;
    console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
    if (isInitiator) {
      doCall();
    }
  }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  sendMessage('bye');
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
      return;
  }
}

function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage({
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate});
  } else {
    console.log('End of candidates.');
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function handleCreateOfferError(event){
  console.log('createOffer() error: ', e);
}

function doCall() {
  console.log('Sending offer to peer');
  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
}

function doAnswer() {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, sdpConstraints);
}

function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
  // Set Opus as the preferred codec in SDP if Opus is present.
  sessionDescription.sdp = preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message' , sessionDescription);
  sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}

function requestTurn(turn_url) {
  var turnExists = false;
  for (var i in pc_config.iceServers) {
    if (pc_config.iceServers[i].url.substr(0, 5) === 'turn:') {
      turnExists = true;
      turnReady = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!turnExists) {
    console.log('Getting TURN server from ', turn_url);
    // No TURN server. Get one from computeengineondemand.appspot.com:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var turnServer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log('Got TURN server: ', turnServer);
        pc_config.iceServers.push({
          'url': 'turn:' + turnServer.username + '@' + turnServer.turn,
          'credential': turnServer.password
        });
        turnReady = true;
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', turn_url, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function handleRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
}

function hangup() {
  console.log('Hanging up.');
  stop();
  sendMessage('bye');
}

function handleRemoteHangup() {
//  console.log('Session terminated.');
  // stop();
  // isInitiator = false;
}

function stop() {
  isStarted = false;
  // isAudioMuted = false;
  // isVideoMuted = false;
  pc.close();
  pc = null;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

// Set Opus as the default audio codec if it's present.
function preferOpus(sdp) {
  var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');
  var mLineIndex=null;
  // Search for m line.
  for (var i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
      if (sdpLines[i].search('m=audio') !== -1) {
        mLineIndex = i;
        break;
      }
  }
  if (mLineIndex === null) {
    return sdp;
  }

  // If Opus is available, set it as the default in m line.
  for (i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
    if (sdpLines[i].search('opus/48000') !== -1) {
      var opusPayload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /:(\d+) opus\/48000/i);
      if (opusPayload) {
        sdpLines[mLineIndex] = setDefaultCodec(sdpLines[mLineIndex], opusPayload);
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  // Remove CN in m line and sdp.
  sdpLines = removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex);

  sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');
  return sdp;
}

function extractSdp(sdpLine, pattern) {
  var result = sdpLine.match(pattern);
  return result && result.length === 2 ? result[1] : null;
}

// Set the selected codec to the first in m line.
function setDefaultCodec(mLine, payload) {
  var elements = mLine.split(' ');
  var newLine = [];
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (index === 3) { // Format of media starts from the fourth.
      newLine[index++] = payload; // Put target payload to the first.
    }
    if (elements[i] !== payload) {
      newLine[index++] = elements[i];
    }
  }
  return newLine.join(' ');
}

// Strip CN from sdp before CN constraints is ready.
function removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex) {
  var mLineElements = sdpLines[mLineIndex].split(' ');
  // Scan from end for the convenience of removing an item.
  for (var i = sdpLines.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var payload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /a=rtpmap:(\d+) CN\/\d+/i);
    if (payload) {
      var cnPos = mLineElements.indexOf(payload);
      if (cnPos !== -1) {
        // Remove CN payload from m line.
        mLineElements.splice(cnPos, 1);
      }
      // Remove CN line in sdp
      sdpLines.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  sdpLines[mLineIndex] = mLineElements.join(' ');
  return sdpLines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possibilities.  Even though you are using the STUN/TURN, maybe some firewall is still blocking the connection somehow?

Other idea is, are you sure the webcam is on and pointed towards a lighted area for the remote server?

You will need to post the full code.

Another possibilities is that your STUN/TURN does not function at all.  You might try different STUN/TURN servers and also check locally/other servers besides on Heroku, like a VPS where you can make sure firewalls are off.

Comment: Yeah my webcam is on and pointed to lighted area. I have tried same 2 devices initially on same network then on different network. I am using Xirsys STUN/TURN server. I think there is no problem with STUN/TURN and problem lies somewhere in the code. Here is the link for full directory-> https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/src/master/complete/step6/

Answer (score 0):

XirSys uses a 30 second TTL on its ICE strings.  In order to use XirSys, you will need to request fresh ICE strings and plug those into your app before every call.  It essentially stops other people leaching your bandwidth.

Lee